# Trouble exporting data to a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble getting the data I am trying to find in one excel sheet to export into another worksheet. I have tried a couple different things and cannot seem to get just the data I want to be exported. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code with the most recent attempt:

```
Public Sub HighlightDups()

    Dim lastRow As Integer, compRow As Integer, rowNo As Integer, lastCol As Integer


    With Sheets("Sheet1")

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        For rowNo = 2 To lastRow
            .Cells(rowNo, lastCol) = Right(.Cells(rowNo, 15), 4)
        Next

        For rowNo = 2 To lastRow
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range(.Cells(2, lastCol), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)), .Cells(rowNo, lastCol), _
            .Range(.Cells(2, 20), .Cells(lastRow, 20)), .Cells(rowNo, 20)) > 1 Then
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNo, 15).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2") _
                .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            End If
        Next
        .Cells(1, lastCol).EntireColumn.ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue? i.e. does it throw an error? does it complete without performing the action? Also a screen print of your sheets and expected sheet will help to resolve the issue

Comment: So the code throws no errors, but it will only bring one piece of data over and place it in row 1. There are way more than one line of data that should be coming up, and unfortunately I cannot provide screen-prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are copying the data to the same row every time. With `.End(xlUp)` in the second For loop you are getting the last populated row, not the one below it, and just overwrite its contents with a new value. Here's the corrected code:

```
Public Sub HighlightDups() 
    Dim lastRow As Integer, compRow As Integer, rowNo As Integer, lastCol As Integer 
    With Sheets("Sheet1") 
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row 
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1 
        For rowNo = 2 To lastRow 
            .Cells(rowNo, lastCol) = Right(.Cells(rowNo, 15), 4) 
        Next 
        For rowNo = 2 To lastRow 
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range(.Cells(2, lastCol), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol)), .Cells(rowNo, lastCol), _ 
            .Range(.Cells(2, 20), .Cells(lastRow, 20)), .Cells(rowNo, 20)) > 1 Then 
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowNo, 15).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2") _ 
                .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0) 'HERE 
            End If 
        Next 
        .Cells(1, lastCol).EntireColumn.ClearContents 
    End With 
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing, this is perfect. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you